# Angular 4 how to create nested Routes levels and context

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Hi I want to build an application in Angular 4 with many levels.
To be more specific.
I want to have a fixed menu (on the left of the screen for example).
This menu must be dynamically generated accordingly the user (different user level means different menu links)
Each link of menu must load a context (“page”) in right of the screen.
Additional each “Page” that loads to the right must have the ability to load more “Pages” in it etc.
So every “page” that loads in context must have the ability to load further “pages” in her body without replace herself.
How can I do this in angular 4?
Should I use Routes or something else?
Thank you

Comment: You can use different components for every type of user or You can store menu items in the storage, then You can request menu for every speceffic user